# Android App icon wont show after building in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, launcher

Am not sure where I am going wrong but I need some support here. 
I tried to fix it by referring to other solutions but, nothing seems to change.

I am trying to display the icon in the android app launcher.

The application installs successfully but after a few changes to the main code. The Android app icon does not show in the app Launcher. 
I always have to use the command *adb shell am start* to start the application from the terminal to launch the application:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.medicalrecordsservice.app.android/.activity.NFCInterfaceActivity
```

My app manifest looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.medicalrecordsservice.app.android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        <activity android:label="Medical Records Service Android App" android:name=".activity.GetAndDisplayRecordsDescriptorsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:label="Medical Records Service Android App" android:name=".activity.CoordinatorActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AuthenticationActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MedicalRecordGetterActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MedicalRecordCreatorActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MedicalRecordsMainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.NFCInterfaceActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/certificate" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Wow, what a terrible question, what are you trying to do, what have you tried? What exactly is not working?  Your question will be buried fast.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. @Booger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified a `<data ... />` element on your intent filter. Consequently, the intent filter will only match intents that contain the MIME type "application/certificate". The launcher intent does not contain that data type. Hence, you activity won't show up in the launcher.

In order to solve this problem, you would decouple the two intent filters (launcher and NFC):

```
<activity android:name=".activity.NFCInterfaceActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/certificate" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note that you do not need to set `android:exported="true"` on activities that specify an intent filter, as those activities will be exported by default. Moreover, the `<uses-permission ... />` elements must be placed *outside* the `<application ... />` element.

Comment: It worked!! However, I have another question.  If I navigate with the back button the `NFCInterfaceActivity` can be bypassed

Comment: Thanks a lot @Micheal Roland  Can I prevent the passing of the `NFCInterfaceActivity`to the next Activity with back navigation button?

Comment: @sheberwok I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Micheal Roland Can you suggest any reading materials to understand how NFCsmart card based mobile Authentication system are developed from the client side to the server side. I have been reading _Smart Card Application Development Using Java_ It helped in understanding several fundamental aspects but would be glad if you could personally recommend me any materials. Reading papers published from on your homepage as well.